# How to make rabbitmq send notifications

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm using rabbitmq with spring, i need to be notified when a message goes to DLQ, is there any way to set up an email notification, for example? I'm thinking of creating a consumer for DLQ and that consumer trigger email, but it will remove the message from the queue and i want it to stay there.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest with the AMQP protocol we send messages to the *Exchanges*, not queues. No body stops you to declare the DLX as `TopicExchange` and have several queues to route the same message for different purposes.

You can find more info in the RabbitMQ [resource](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html).